# How to prevent hiding of the resizable view?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, resize, webix

Is there a way to prevent total hiding of the view using resizer in Webix? Such possibility is extremely unwanted, but I've no idea how to do his right. 
Here's a [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/66563249) of the following code:

```
webix.ui({                
  rows:[    
    {},
    {view:"resizer"},
    {view:"datatable", data:grid_data, autoConfig:true},
    {view:"resizer"},
    {cols:[
      { },
      { view:"resizer" },
      { }   
    ]}
  ]
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use minWidth and minHeight attributes, to limit the minimum size of any view.

```
webix.ui({                
  rows:[    
    { minHeight:100 },
    {view:"resizer"},
    { minHeight:100, view:"datatable", data:grid_data, autoConfig:true}
]});
```

Check the updated snippet. 
http://webix.com/snippet/46215c0a